# Without #import, does Swift have its own easy way to detect circular dependencies?

Tags: swift

```
#import "whatever.h"
```

...wasn't perfect, but it was very handy for diagnosing circular dependencies, not to mention enforcing modularity.

You could be certain which classes knew about other classes--with the flick of a finger.

If you had to, you could comment out *all* the import statements, and add them back one at a time, in order to diagnose a dependency issue. It wasn't necessarily fast but it was dead simple.

And if a class didn't import anything other than the obligatory headers, Son, that's one modular class you had there!

If your project had ten classes that didn't import anything, then you knew that they were ten modular classes--you didn't have to package each class into its own Framework or anything like that. Easy.

But now, with Swift's policy of "everybody knows about everything all the time", it seems like it's just down to personal vigilance to sustain modularity. Personal vigilance is the worst kind!

Am I missing something? Is there a way to do these things easily in Swift?

Comment: Use modules.  Everything knows about everything else *within the module*.

Comment: I think there may be a misunderstanding of the emphasis I'm placing on easiness. I'm looking for something comparably easy to #import statements, which let you pop access on and off with the flick of a finger.

Comment: You need to think of your separate Swift files as one big Objective-C file in a sense.  If something needs to be **modularized**, then it needs to be in its own **module** (and guess how you pop access on and off to modules?  With an `import` statement.)

Comment: Is it your opinion that creating modules approaches the convenience of writing #import statements?  Here's what came up at the top of a search for "Swift modules easy": http://railsware.com/blog/2014/06/26/creation-of-pure-swift-module/ (...that's not easy...)

Comment: Do you want *easy*?  Or do you want **right**?

Comment: The inquiry placing easiness and rightness in a dichotomy seems intended to deride easiness as a criteria for a good solution to the problem. Nonetheless, I prize it.

Comment: By the way, creating *modules* isn't as hard as that blog makes it out to be.  That blog is making a **LIBRARY**, not a **MODULE**.  Making a Swift module is as simple as creating a new target, choosing "Framework & Library" and choosing Cocoa (or Cocoa Touch) Framework, hitting "Next" and giving it a name.  That's it...

Answer (score 7):

If you want to modularize your Swift code, you should be using *modules*!

Creating a new module is pretty simple.

Add a new target to your project by clicking the plus sign here:

[image]

Select "Framework & Library" for the appropriate platform (iOS/OS X):

[image]

Choose "Cocoa Framework" (or Cocoa Touch, platform dependent) and click Next:

[image]

Give your module a name and change the language to Swift (or leave it as Objective-C, it doesn't matter, you can use both).

[image]

Add a Swift file to your module:

[image]

Add some code to your Swift file.  Note, the default access level for Swift is `internal` which means it can be accessed from anywhere within the *module* but not from outside the module.  Any code which we want to use outside the module must be given the `public` access level.

```
public class ModularSwift {
    public init(){}
    public var foo: Int = 0
}
```

Be sure to *build* your module (Cmd+B):

[image]

Go back to your original target, import the module and start using its code:

```
import MyModularSwiftCode

let foo = ModularSwift()
```

Xcode is perfectly happy:

[image]

Now, comment out the `import` statement and notice the errors:

[image]

Comment: I can't believe you'd compare this to the ease of #import statements! :) ...that said, this is an *extremely* helpful guide, and it does look like this is the best we're going to get. Practically, it means that I'm going to write everything first and then chop it up into modules near the end of the project, which isn't that bad a way of doing things. Thank you very much, this will be really helpful.

Comment: It's just as easy. The "hard part" is setting up the code modularly... But if the code isn't in separate modules, you shouldn't consider it separable.

Comment: This is a great help. We don't have to agree about how easy it is. The fact is you went to a good bit effort to explain this well, and I really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @nhgrif--this is immediately causing build failures and the kind of stream-of-text XCode errors that in general mean, to me, "stop everything and restore from previous commit."